# What is the benefit of using class method instead of init instance , and vice versa?

Tags: iphone, collections

If I write:

```
NSArray *arr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Liza", @"Lipi", @"Rose"];
NSArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Liza", @"Lipi", @"Rose"];
```

both the statements will do the same thing. Then what is the difference between these two statements, and what is the benefit of using one over other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older days...  if you used first one, you needed to `release` the `arr`.

While second releases an `autorelease`d object.

Now in ARC, the autoreleased is put by the compiler.

BENEFIT:  `arrayWithObjects:` is concise and doesn't require one extra method call.

Comment: Well, it's more concise, but it will call an extra method call, since it is just a convenience function for the combination of `alloc` and `initWithObjects:`.

Comment: Then in ARC both have the same meaning , right? @Anoop Vaidya

Comment: @liza: Ultimately both will end to same. But one is class method, another one is instance method. Sometimes you dont need an instance of array but just to use it in dictionary. then you go with class method. I think you are getting me.

Comment: @liza:  Are you from india?

Comment: @liza: thats great :) And php+ios even more.

Answer (score 2):

The second is a convenience method which returns an autoreleased array, the first would need to be memory managed. Under ARC these are equivalent and with array literals both are probably more verbose than what you need, use `@[@"Liza", @"Lipi", @"Rose"]` instead

Comment: 4.4 has been out for almost 6 months, any reason to not use it?

Answer (score 1):

In the first statement you are the owner of the generated instance (so you are responsible for releasing it as well if not using `ARC`) while in the other you are not (the array is auto released for you). (behind the scenes the `alloc` and `init` are called by the `NSArray` implementation)